# File handle for output according to the iteration in a loop

Tags: perl

I need to go through certain numbers and find those numbers in a certain string and then according to that I need to output it to a certain file. Basically, my question is how would I open a file handle to output in the loop according to the loop iteration?

Example Code:

```
$rec_1= "481";

for my $all (@seq)
{ 
  my $match = index($rec_1, $seq[$all]);
  if ($match != -1)
  {
    # I want to open a file handle and output the contents of rec_1
    # accordingly. (there will be 12 different files in the end.)
  }
  else 
  {
    # print the data from rec_1 to not matches (another file)
  }
}
```

In total I know there will be 12 sequences that I will have to look though so I need to check that if the sequence is there I simply go through the `rec_1` data and if `rec_1` contains that sequence I add it to the file that has the previous data.

Comment: How do you get to 12 different files? Give us a sample of the combined input that you want to fan out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of FileHandles like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use FileHandle;

my @fh;
$fh[0] = FileHandle->new;
$fh[0]->open( ">file0") or die "open failed";
my $i = 0;
$fh[$i]->print("Output for file 0");
```

Comment: Prefer [IO::File](http://p3rl.org/IO::File) over FileHandle to cut out one useless layer of indirection.